# Django Rest Framework - Filter by custom field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have Serializer which defines a custom column, in the serializers.py which I am trying to filter a query on.

The itemsoutstanding column example below, I am trying to filter it from my view but it returns "is not defined"

```
class OverView(serializers.ModelSerializer):

itemsoutstanding = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','total_price', 'created_at','itemsoutstanding']


    def get_itemsoutstanding(self, obj):
        count= Items.objects.filter(order=obj.id).count()
        return count
```

In my view I am trying to filter on the serializer column, but it says it's not defined

```
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OverView

     queryset = Order.objects.filter(shop=shop)
     queryset = queryset.filter(itemsoutstanding> 0)
```

Is there any way to filter based on the serializer columns?

Comment: What is `shop` here?

Comment: The field has to be annotated in the view. Please post your models and describe the field you need if you need help with the annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to annotate the queryset in the definition, you may need to check the [django docs for annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and probably adjust this code to your models but the idea is this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
queryset = Order.objects.annotate(itemsoutstanding=Count("items"))
```

Then you can use the `itemsoutstanting` in the filter and in the serializer as a field:

```
class OverView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','total_price', 'created_at','itemsoutstanding']
```

Answer (score 0):

The queryset has nothing to do with the serializer, so it does not know of your defined field in the serializer. That custom field is only added to the serialized data and not the queryset. What you need to do is annotate the field in the view when you get the queryset.